# SQL Queries aren't outputting what I would like them to do

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Here is my query:

```
Select * into [HowToFix_onefile]  from  [actions_onefile]

ALTER TABLE
    HowToFix_onefile
ADD [HowToFix] AS
    CASE 
         WHEN [Error Messages] LIKE 'Different Security Type%'  AND NOT [Actions] = 'not being scanned' THEN 'Change to NFS'
         WHEN [Error Messages] LIKE 'Pruned%'  AND NOT [Actions] = 'not being scanned' THEN 'Change to NFS'
         WHEN [Error Messages] LIKE '%mismatch%' AND NOT [Actions] = 'not being scanned' THEN 'Change to NFS'
         WHEN [Error Messages] LIKE '%mismatch%' AND [protocol] LIKE 'CIFS' AND [Scanned] LIKE 'Yes' THEN 'Backend problem. Security is not visible'
         WHEN [Error Messages] LIKE 'Access%' AND NOT [Actions] = 'not being scanned' THEN 'Give permission to Varonis'
         WHEN [Error Messages] LIKE 'The inherited%' OR [Error Messages] LIKE '%path%' OR [Error Messages] LIKE 'missing inheritance%' THEN 'Ignore Error'      
         WHEN [protocol] LIKE 'NFS' AND [DirsCount] = 0 AND [Scanned] = 'in Shares table, but not SortedDirectoryTree properties' THEN 'Backend problems. Security is not visible'
         WHEN [protocol] LIKE 'CIFS' AND  [Scanned] = 'in Shares table, but not SortedDirectoryTree properties' THEN 'Backend problems. Security is not visible'
         WHEN [Protocol] LIKE 'CIFS & NIFS%' AND [Scanned] = 'in Shares table, but not SortedDirectoryTree properties' THEN 'Change to NFS'
        ELSE '' END
```

For instance, this output is suppose to look like:

> *CIFS* Monitor type *mismatch* actual security type (1)   *Yes*   Needs
>   action    **Backend problem. Security is not visible.**

But instead it looks like:

> CIFS  Monitor type mismatch actual security type (1)  Yes Needs
>   action    **Change to NFS**

It is supposed to say 'Backend problem. Security is not visible.' This is because it meets the criteria: the protocol is CIFS, the error has a 'mismatch' in it, and scanned is 'Yes'. Shown as italicized.

I've tried switching the orders, playing around with the '%', but it's still not working. Would appreciate some advice!

Comment: Using `CASE` order of `WHEN` is crucial. You should start from the most specific ones and set general at the end.

Comment: try '[Actions] <>...' instead of 'not actions...'

Comment: You are checking different criteria for those 2 cases.  You need to ensure that it should fail the one listed first -- [Actions] filter -- if it meets these criteria you will get that result, and never hit the check for the next case.  If this is what is happening, you need to fix your case evaluation such that it cannot pass both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an ordering problem.  This ordering should solve this particular problem, but might introduce others:

```
     WHEN [Error Messages] LIKE '%mismatch%' AND [protocol] LIKE 'CIFS' AND [Scanned] LIKE 'Yes' THEN 'Backend problem. Security is not visible'
     WHEN [Error Messages] LIKE 'Different Security Type%'  AND NOT [Actions] = 'not being scanned' THEN 'Change to NFS'
     WHEN [Error Messages] LIKE 'Pruned%'  AND NOT [Actions] = 'not being scanned' THEN 'Change to NFS'
     WHEN [Error Messages] LIKE '%mismatch%' AND NOT [Actions] = 'not being scanned' THEN 'Change to NFS'
     WHEN [Error Messages] LIKE 'Access%' AND NOT [Actions] = 'not being scanned' THEN 'Give permission to Varonis'
     WHEN [Error Messages] LIKE 'The inherited%' OR [Error Messages] LIKE '%path%' OR [Error Messages] LIKE 'missing inheritance%' THEN 'Ignore Error'      
     WHEN [protocol] LIKE 'NFS' AND [DirsCount] = 0 AND [Scanned] = 'in Shares table, but not SortedDirectoryTree properties' THEN 'Backend problems. Security is not visible'
     WHEN [protocol] LIKE 'CIFS' AND  [Scanned] = 'in Shares table, but not SortedDirectoryTree properties' THEN 'Backend problems. Security is not visible'
     WHEN [Protocol] LIKE 'CIFS & NIFS%' AND [Scanned] = 'in Shares table, but not SortedDirectoryTree properties' THEN 'Change to NFS'
    ELSE '' END
```